# Laravel 5.2 deep linking without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, may be there are some good examples how to implement deep links in it?
I'm trying to implement smth like this: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/crawling/

I added all js scripts as it is in example above, but nothing works, it refreshes rages as before, anything else I should do?

Help please!

UPD:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navHeaderCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img alt="Home" src="/img/logo.png"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">{{ strtoupper(trans('header.homepage')) }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="/estates">{{ strtoupper(trans('header.estates')) }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="/addEstate">{{ strtoupper(trans('header.addEstate')) }}</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/contact">{{ strtoupper(trans('header.contact')) }}</a></li>
                @if (!Auth::guest())
                    <!-- other links -->
                @endif


                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <!-- Languages -->
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('/estates', 'PagesController@estates');
Route::get('/addEstate', 'PagesController@addEstate');
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('/register', 'PagesController@register');
```

JS script:

```
$.address.init(function() {

// Initializes plugin support for links
$('a:not([href^=https])').address();

// Adds a simple hover effect
$('.nav a').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

}).change(function(event) {

// Identifies the page selection
var page = event.parameters.page ? '/?page=' + event.parameters.page : event.path;

// Highlights the selected link
$('.nav a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == (page == '/' ? '#' : '#!' + page)) {
        $(this).addClass('selected').focus();
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
});

var handler = function(data) {
    $('.content').html($('.content', data).html()).parent().show();
    $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
};

// Loads the page content and inserts it into the content area
$.ajax({
    url: location.pathname + '?_escaped_fragment_=' + encodeURIComponent(event.value),
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        handler(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        handler(data);
    }
});

});

// Hides the page during initialization
document.write('<style type="text/css"> .page { display: none; } </style>');
```

Comment: Post the code you've written / are using -- it's very difficult to help you without seeing what you're working on...

Comment: Sorry for delay pls, I updated main post

Comment: where's the javascript that would interact with clicks on `<a>` tags? If you don't want page refresh you need to use ajax to get the content